# Database creation error in Qt

Tags: c++, database, qt, qt4

I am using this code to create a database. But I am getting "false" in debug. I tried a lot but its not working. What is the error in this?

```
 QSqlQuery query;
qDebug() << query.exec("CREATE TABLE glucose (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, value INTEGER, date TEXT, time TEXT, duration TEXT, note TEXT");

   qDebug() << query.prepare("INSERT INTO glucose(id, value, date, time, duration, note)""VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

   query.bindValue(1,edit_glucose->text().toInt());

   query.bindValue(2,datetime->date());

  query.bindValue(3,datetime->time());

  query.bindValue(4,"a");

   query.bindValue(5,edit_note->toPlainText());
   qDebug() << query.exec();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forget to  close your  `CREATE TABLE` query with  `")"`

Answer (score 2):

QSqlQuery has the method lastError(), returns error information :)

Comment: yes I have used that :  qDebug()<< query.lastError();
But its showing error : binary '<<' no operator found which can takes a left hand operand of type Qdebug(there is no acceptable conversion).

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in the `INSERT` query the `id` field. You must remove it.

The query should be:

```
Debug() << query.prepare("INSERT INTO glucose(value, date, time, duration, note) 
                                      VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```